# How to get the context from API messages Directly

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to get the context directly from Controller API/Messages for prompting a dialog

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {

        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
          PromptDialog.Text(context, getText, "GetText");
        }

     }
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, there is not any proper direct way to do this. BUT, you can use the 
following code which has the same functionality as you want (I hope this helps):

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{

    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
         await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<string>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        PromptDialog.Text(context, MessageReceived, "How are You?");
    }
    private async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        context.Done(message);
    }
}
```

Indeed, it is a dialog which works as a wrapper for promptDialog.